# Android Webview video player cose when it complete play

Tags: android, vimeo, android-video-player

I trying to play  vimeo video using web view .I want to close video player when it complete play.How can i do it.I try it for two day but i did not get any solution .please help

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030524/auto-playing-vimeo-videos-in-android-webview?rq=1