# Listen to vimeo Player events using JavaScriptInterface in Android

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I am displaying a vimeo player inside a WebView on Android.
My question is:I need track the "play" event and "pause" event or even the "progress of the video" using JavaScriptInterface how can I achieve this ?

Comment: See :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348

Answer (score 2):

You can find a full implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030524/auto-playing-vimeo-videos-in-android-webview). You can also get the embed html for a video using the [vimeo-networking-java SDK](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java). But the part you need to know is:

```
froogaloop.addEvent('playProgress', function(data) {
               if(!showingPlayer && data.percent > 0) {
                  showingPlayer = true;
                  jQuery('.froog_container_class').show();
                  jQuery('.froog_container_class').css('height', '_windowHeight');
                  jQuery('.froog_container_class').css('width', '_windowWidth');
                  /* Most tablets I tested aren't quick enough to make this work
                     but one can still hope */
                  jQuery('#loading').fadeOut('slow');
               }
           });
```